# Get 3 Random elements and 1 preset element from HashSet

Tags: c#, linq

I'll explain,
I am making a simple trivia.
I need to get 3 wrong answers and 1 correct answer into an Array.
I declare hashtable and fill it with data:

```
 private static readonly HashSet<string> DifferentAnswers= new HashSet<string>();
```

This HashSet includes all possible answers from a category, **including correct answer.**

Currently i am doing the following to get 3 wrong answers:

**Note**: `CorrectAnswer` variable is the absolute correct answer in string type

```
DifferentAnswers
  .OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid())
  .Take(3)
  .Where(n => n != CorrectAnswer)
  .ToArray();
```

Is there a way to get 3 incorrect answers and 1 correct answer into an array in different order in 1 fancy Linq (Total 4 items) ? :)

Afterwards i will check the number of correct answer in array.

Comment: What means _in different order_?

Comment: That correct answer will not always be in a specific place in array.

Comment: If there is only one correct answer, why you store it with the incorrect at all? You could save the information if the correct answer was given

Comment: @Tim Schmelter You are right that it can be done that way and logically it might be even more correct, however, this is how the system work, it helps to simplify other parts, unless i will be proven wrong later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can 'concat' additional list of items to your IEnumerable, but you probably will want to re-shuffle them afterwards:

```
DifferentAnswers
  .OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid())
  .Where(n => n != CorrectAnswer)
  //Needs to be after the Where
  .Take(3)
  // added:
  .Concat(new [] {CorrectAnswer})
  .OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid())
  //
  .ToArray();
```

(of course it assumes you know the `CorrectAnswer` upfront, just like your example code suggested)

Comment: This could cause to return only 3 elements instead of 4 (after a few executions). https://dotnetfiddle.net/nIQ4Uu

Comment: @Dror that bit of it comes from your own code, though :p

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/B9KDR4 Not sure it's a bit of my code. or least i don't see it. You get "Index was outside the bounds of the array." After a few executions.

Comment: @Dror: my addition was `.Concat(new [] {CorrectAnswer}) .OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid())` and it solves the problem of `I have 3 wrong answers and I want to have the correct one included too`. Neither Concat nor OrderBy could remove any element from the result nor could throw IndexArrayBlargh, so whatever you see, it's a bug in your original code and I preserved it. The problem is that you (a) first shuffle (b) then take 3 (c) then filter-out the CorrectOne. You should do A+C+B, or else Take(3) may sometimes pick wrong-good-wrong, then filter-out the correct one and be left with 2 wrongs = boom.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I get you, Thanks for the explanation. This could be solved by placing the Take(3) after the  `Where(n => n != CorrectAnswer)    ---> .Where(n => n != CorrectAnswer).Take(3)`

Comment: You right, my initial error. I have updated your answer.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication51
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Question
        {
            public int number { get; set; }
            public string question { get; set; }
            public string answer { get; set; }
            public List<string> wrongAnswer { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Question> test = new List<Question>() {
                new Question() { number = 1, question = "Question 1", answer = "Answer 1", wrongAnswer = new List<string>() { "Wrong Answer 1","Wrong Answer 2","Wrong Answer 3"}},
                new Question() { number = 2, question = "Question 2", answer = "Answer 2", wrongAnswer = new List<string>() { "Wrong Answer 1","Wrong Answer 2","Wrong Answer 3"}},
                new Question() { number = 3, question = "Question 3", answer = "Answer 3", wrongAnswer = new List<string>() { "Wrong Answer 1","Wrong Answer 2","Wrong Answer 3"}},
                new Question() { number = 4, question = "Question 4", answer = "Answer 4", wrongAnswer = new List<string>() { "Wrong Answer 1","Wrong Answer 2","Wrong Answer 3"}},
                new Question() { number = 5, question = "Question 5", answer = "Answer 5", wrongAnswer = new List<string>() { "Wrong Answer 1","Wrong Answer 2","Wrong Answer 3"}}
            };

            Random rand = new Random();

            var results = test.OrderBy(x => x.number).Select(x => new List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>() { new KeyValuePair<int,string>(rand.Next(), x.answer), new KeyValuePair<int,string>(rand.Next(), x.wrongAnswer[0]),new KeyValuePair<int,string>(rand.Next(), x.wrongAnswer[1]),new KeyValuePair<int,string>(rand.Next(), x.wrongAnswer[2])})
                .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Key).Select(y => y.Value).ToList()).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```